Trying booting into Debian on MacBook Air shows black screen
I'm trying to install Debian on a MacBookAir ( as dual-boot or as a single, I don't care that much).
Every time I select "EFI Boot", laptop goes into the black screen. After a while I hear it is processing something, but it is still black screen.
Below are the specifications and steps that I did:
MacBook Air8.1 Intel Core i5

In Recovery Mode, under Utilities > Startup Security Utility I allowed "External Boot: Allow booting from external or removable media". All secure boots are disabled.
I tried following images (and I checked shasum, they are correct)
debian-12.8.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso
debian-12.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso

1/ Created a Bootable USB using balenaEtcher.
2/ Switched on MacBook and hold option to launch the boot menu.
3/ Selected "EFI Boot".
4/ And then the screen goes black.
I tried to press "E", "ESC" or "Shift" immediately after selecting "EFI Boot" hoping to get to get GRUB bootloader menu, but none of it worked.
What should I do to install debian? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you a lot for the support and advice!

There are two important things to consider when using recent Macs with Linux:

A good bootloader / bootmanager;
Use specific kernel patches for better hardware support.

All recent MacBooks (including the Intel ones with Core i5 and Core i7 processors) use the T2 security ship.  Although they can boot recent vanilla kernels, especially for MacBooks, it is strongly advisable for you to use patches so that they can recognize a number of devices, including the keyboard and the touchpad, otherwise unusable (requiring an external USB keyboard).
As for the EFI boot, I recommend installing Refind, an EFI bootloader and bootmanager that can boot MacOS, Linux and Windows.  Refind is based on Refit, another boot loader developed specifically for Mac, but it is no longer maintained, so I'm not posting the link for the second to avoid confusion.
References:

Refind
Linux T2 patches


thank you for the answer. As mentioned in the post, my MacBook Air has Intel Core i5.

No, my friend ALL Macs from 2018 on, including the intel ones have the T2 security chip installed alongside.  Do not make confusion between T2 and M1/2/3/4 processors.  The T2 is not a replacement for the main processor.  I have 3 intel Macs, all Core i7 and all have the T2 chip.  Believe me, all links I put in my answer will help you if you look at them carefully.  And by the way, Refind is a fantastic boot loader/manager I use in my Macs to dual boot long before the M* and T2 chips even exist.  Hope this clarifies and help.

All Mac models containing the T2 Security Chip: https://support.apple.com/en-in/103265.
Link on how to determine if your model has the T2 chip: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/11/20/mac-models-t2-chip-howto/

I'm getting it now, thank you a lot for explaining! Refind helped me further already, however, it gets "frozen" when I try to select the language. I can't just move the "pointer". Do you have any advice for me how to do it? I'm trying to instal Debian, not Linux though.

At what point exactly did your mouse pointer freeze?  I don't use mouse with refind, just the keyboard.  If you refer to the mouse or keyboard not working after booting Linux, this is because they are not recognized if you don't have the BCE driver (a kernel module).  It used to be a separate driver, but its now included in the kernel patches I pointed out in the answer.  (note this will require recompiling the kernel).  BTW, Debian is a Linux distribution, so, if you are installing Debian, you are installing Linux.

I don't have much experience with Debian, though, as I use a different distributtion named Fedora.  BUT, my suggestion for you:  Plug in a USB mouse and a USB keyboard, then complete the installation.  This will give you access to a working system.  After that you will have the chance to recompile your kernel and include the T2 kernel patches.  Note: Recompiling the kernel is note exactly a trivial task for Linux beginners, but there are a number of tutorials in the Web.  In the end, don't blame Debian or Linux, all this difficulty is due to Apple not making the specs available.

So, without the specs, it is very hard for the community to develop drivers for these proprietary hardware.  They already exist with some re-engineering (in the form of the patches I put in the answer, but they are just not in the mainline kernel yet).

thank you a lot for such a comprehensive answer. And yes, the keyboard is not working anymore, so I can't select the language. Is there any way to do it without the external keyboard?

Unfortunately for the keyboard and mouse to work, the kernel driver must be loaded, and this requires the specific for the exact kernel version running and the installation media doesn't have since this is not part of the mainstream (official) Linux kernel.  So you'll have to do the installation with USB devices attached and then compile the drivers yourself for finally installing it.  Maybe you could google for terms like Apple T2 debian installation. May someone did create an installer.  Warning: you will be downloading community contributed software, so cautiong is advised to avoid malware.

Refer to these links (which I consider reliable): https://wiki.t2linux.org/distributions/fedora/installation/ and
https://wiki.t2linux.org/guides/preinstall/
I'm not sure if you have a specific need to install Debian, there are many other distributions available (none directly support Apple T2, but the links I provided above include instructions for several of them, although Debian is not included).
If there isn't a very specific reason, you could stick with Ubuntu, which is Debian based and widely more adopted.  (I personally use Fedora, but Ubuntu is much more "Debianish")

OBS: Patching and compiling the kernel is not such a trivial task, so I'd go for the links above as they have simpler methods with very good step-by-step instructions.  Good luck and, if you have the chance and believe it all was helpful, up vote my answer.

I can't respond to your comment because I'm new and don't have enough "reputation"... stupid concept if you ask me, but I digress... The T2 is a security chip inside Apple laptops and desktops (including the Intel ones). It is separate from the processor. Your MBA has a T2 chip internally, which as @Marcelo stated can cause issues with booting. My personal advice, unless you have a specific reason to boot Debian (which has numerous problems with Macs), use Ubuntu since it is Debian based and includes drivers for Macs out of the box.
I will also continue to research the specific issue with Debian on an MBA 8,1 and respond when I've got more of an answer for you.

Hi, my laptop is MacBook Air8.1 with Intel Core i5. There is no T2 chip.

All Mac models containing the T2 Security Chip: https://support.apple.com/en-in/103265
Link on how to determine if your model has the T2 chip: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/11/20/mac-models-t2-chip-howto/

Explicit reference on Macbook Air 8,1 and the T2 chip: https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/solved-with-t2-kernel-2019-macbook-air-8-1-bcm4355-wifi-not-working/18632
